# Call recording on Jailbroken iPhone

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I wanted to develop call recording module on **Jailbroken iPhone** device. And it looks certainly possible as some of the call recording apps are already there in cydia store. But couldn't get any proper info to proceed towards implementing it... If any one got proper idea over it please let me know...

Comment: updating the Findings: It seems that most of the app that claims to record the calls doesn't do it on device itself. They just give a access point to make call and that access point acts as middle layer and records the app.